# Writing continued fractions of irrational numbers as infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

Infinite sums have been formulated for famous irrational numbers, such as $\pi, \phi,e,\sqrt2$ and a few others that can be listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_notable_numbers#Irrational_and_suspected_irrational_numbers) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/goldenmeanseries/):

---

Here are some examples: (There are more examples if you follow the links above)

$$\sqrt 2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^{3k+1} (k!)^2}}$$
$$\pi = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(2^{k+1})(k!)^2}{2k+1}}$$
$$\phi = \frac{13}{8} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{((-1)^{k+1})(2k+1)!}{((k+2)!)(k!)(4^{2k+3})}}$$
$$e =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{k!}}$$

---

In the section that follows I will just be discussing **non-transcendental** numbers (such as $\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5$, etc (not $\pi,e$, etc)

As far as I know there are no known infinite sums for $\sqrt3,\sqrt5$ and irrational numbers such which can be written as $\sqrt[a]b$ Where $a$ is an real number > 0, and b is a prime number or the product of prime numbers. And such that $\sqrt[a]b$ is ***not*** an integer (perfect squares or perfect cubes).

**However**, there are continued fractions which can represent some of these numbers, such as $\sqrt5$:

$$\sqrt5 = 2+ \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4 + ...}}}}}}$$

This wikipedia section discusses this concept nicely: [Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Roots_of_positive_numbers)

---

### **SO MY QUESTION IS:**

**If there is a continued fraction for $\sqrt x$, then how do we go from the continued fraction to an infinite sum?** (Conversion maybe?) Let's take $\sqrt5$ as an example:

---

How I thought of doing this, would to work out rational approximations by taking the continued fraction to certain terms (T), such as:

- T1 = $2 = \frac{2}{1}$
- T2 = $2+ \frac{1}{4} = \frac{9}{4} = 2,25$
- T3 = $2+ \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{38}{17} = 2,234294118...$
- T4 = $2+ \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{4}}} = \frac{161}{72} = 2,236111111...$
- T5 = $2+ \frac{1}{4 + \frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{4}}}} = \frac{682}{305} = 2,236065574...$
- T(n) = $\frac{T_{n+1}(OEIS: A001077)}{T_{n+1}(OEIS: A001076)}$

and the list goes on (if we did this "infinitely" many times we should theoretically reach $\sqrt5$ and that is what we are looking for :)

Then what I tried to do is take these rational approximations and finding the difference between them, so we could then write it as an infinite sum, comprising of adding the differences (D) of these rational approximations.

- $D1 = T2-T1 = \frac{9}{4} - 2 = \frac{1}{4}$
- $D2 = T3-T2 = \frac{38}{17} - \frac{9}{4} = -\frac{1}{68}$
- $D3 = T4-T3 = \frac{161}{72} - \frac{38}{17} = \frac{1}{1224}$
- $D4 = T5-T4 = \frac{682}{305} - \frac{161}{72} = -\frac{1}{21960}$

The numerator stays 1 and the denominators continue in the following sequence: https://oeis.org/A156084 (Each time the term alternates between being positive and negative). Let's call the absolute value of each term in the sequence $a_k$, $(a_1 = \frac{1}{4},a_2 = \frac{1}{68})$;  then$\sqrt5$ could be written as:

$$\sqrt5 =  2 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k} . {a_{k+1}} = 2 + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{68} + \frac{1}{1224} - \frac{1}{21960} ...$$

---

Kind Regards

Joshua

Comment: Oh, I agree, it's better to include a link than to list _too many_ examples. I think you struck a good balance. (And now my earlier comment is irrelevant, so I  deleted it.)

Comment: @DavidK So did I ;) Anyways, Have you got an idea of how to approach this? I mean, if there was a way to write https://oeis.org/A156084 as a sequence, it might be easier, but it can only be written as a recursive formula

Comment: Isn't the taylor series for the square root a solution for your initial problem?

Comment: @N74 The reason I would Iike to go from a continued fraction to an infinite sum is because the continued fraction contains integers... And I would like the infinite sum to contain only integers. Does the Taylor series contain only integers?

Comment: Hmm, after you have already written your valid solution for converting the cont.frac of $\sqrt{5}$ into a series - what is still the question? An explicite formula for the terms?

Comment: In principle, you could also proceed by making the series an iterated product: $\sqrt{5}=2+\frac14 \cdot (1-\frac1{17}\cdot (1-\frac1{18}\cdot (1-\frac{17}{305}\cdot (1-\frac{18}{323}\cdot (1-\frac{305}{5473}\cdot (1- \cdots ))))))$ to get smaller numbers in the denominators...

Comment: You shouldn't ask for upvotes.  Its kinda against the rules or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

There is at least one formula to convert any series to a continued fraction
provided none of the terms in the series is zero; see [this page from NIST](http://dlmf.nist.gov/3.10). But you already have a continued fraction
and you're trying to go in the opposite direction (to find the formula
for an equal series).

There are also formulas to convert *some* continued fractions to series,
for example [in this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2005576?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

I don't know of a general formula that applies to your examples,
but I notice that if $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 1$, and
$a_n = 4a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 3$, then
$T_1 - 2 = \frac{a_1}{a_2}$, and in general, for $n \geq 1$,
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{4a_{n+1} + a_n}
 = \frac{1}{4 + \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}}
$$
So if we set $T_n = 2 + \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ then in general
$$
T_{n+1} - 2 = \frac{1}{4+(T_n - 2)},
$$
which is the recursion exhibited by your continued fraction for $\sqrt5$.

A closed-form formula for $a_n$ (eliminating the recursion) is
$$
a_n = \frac{(2+\sqrt5)^{n-1} - (2-\sqrt5)^{n-1}}{2\sqrt5}
    = \frac{\phi^{3(n-1)} - (-\phi)^{-3(n-1)}}{2\sqrt5}
$$
where $\phi$ is the golden ratio, $\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$.

As you observed, the finite expansions of the continued fraction are equal to the partial sums of a series whose general term is
$T_{n+1}-T_n$. 
Substituting the closed forms of $a_n$, $a_{n+1}$, and $a_{n+2}$
and simplifying, we get
\begin{align}
T_{n+1}-T_n &= \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}} - \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}
= \frac{a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n+2} a_n}{a_{n+2} a_{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{a_{n+2} a_{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\phi^{6n+9} + (-\phi)^{-6n-9} + 4(-1)^n} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2+\sqrt5)^{2n+3} + (2-\sqrt5)^{-2n-3} + 4(-1)^n}.
\end{align}

This might seem a little disappointing at first because the closed form
of the general term for your sequence for $\sqrt5$ involves $\sqrt5$ itself,
but if you expand each term symbolically (treating $\sqrt5$ as a symbol,
not substituting a decimal approximation), the odd powers of $\sqrt5$
cancel out and you're left with just rational numbers.
Still, it might be easier after all to just use the recursive formula
for $a_n$ to generate each successive term $T_{n+1}-T_n$.

---

By the way, you can also obtain a series for $\sqrt5$ by
considering $\sqrt5 = 2\left(1+\frac14\right)^{1/2}$ and
using the binomial theorem to expand
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac14\right)^{1/2} &= 1 + \frac12\cdot\frac14 +
\frac{1}{2!}\cdot\frac12\left(-\frac12\right)\left(\frac14\right)^2
+ \frac{1}{3!}\cdot\frac12\left(-\frac12\right)
\left(-\frac32\right)\left(\frac14\right)^3 + \cdots \\
&= 1 + \frac18 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k+1)!!}{8^{k+2}(k+2)!}\\
&= 1 + \frac18 - \frac{1}{128} + \frac{1}{1024} - \frac{5}{32768}
     + \frac{7}{262144} - \frac{21}{4194304} + - \cdots
\end{align}
where $(2k+1)!!$ is the double factorial 
$(2k+1)!! = (2k+1)(2k-1)\cdots5\cdot3\cdot1$,
but this converges a lot slower than your continued fraction.

Comment: do you maybe think this can be solved by finding the general formula for the denominators of the differences? https://oeis.org/A156084 instead of using a recursive formula.... But is there even a way to go from recursive to general formula?

Comment: @JoshuaLochner This particular recursion does have a closed form, which turns out to be useful for simplifying $T_{n+1}-T_n$, so I've added that to the answer. I doubt there's a really general formula to handle square roots of other primes or products of primes, but I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the convergents to the continued fraction to obtain series, since the convergents give close rational approximations to $5$.
$\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}$

Using $\sqrt{5} \approx \lfrac{9}{4}$ we get:

> $\sqrt{5} = \lfrac94 ( 1 - \lfrac1{9^2} )^\lfrac12 = \lfrac{9}{4} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} \lfrac{(-1)^k}{9^{2k}} = \lfrac{9}{4} - \lfrac{9}{4} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lfrac{2 \cdot (2k-2)!}{k! \cdot (k-1)! \cdot 18^{2k}}$.

Using $\sqrt{5} \approx \frac{38}{17}$ we get:

> $\sqrt{5} = \lfrac{38}{17} ( 1 + \lfrac1{38^2} )^\lfrac12 = \lfrac{38}{17} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} \lfrac{1}{38^{2k}} = \lfrac{38}{17} - \lfrac{38}{17} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lfrac{(-1)^k \cdot 2 \cdot (2k-2)!}{k! \cdot (k-1)! \cdot 76^{2k}}$.

Comment: Any things I could look at? References or external papers?

Comment: that's a smart solution indeed

Comment: @JoshuaLochner: This is a very basic application of the general binomial expansion (which can be proven by the Taylor series). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series.

Comment: @GCab: Well this might answer the question here, but it's extremely slow (linear convergence) for computing square-roots as compared to Newton-Raphson approximation (quadratic convergence), which gives a rational approximation at every iteration (but it's just a sequence, not a series).

Comment: @user21820, yes in fact the approximation methods generate a sequence, with not too a complicated recurrence.; but difficult to convert into a series

Comment: How would you know what rational approximations (I know you can use any) but how would you subsequently choose whether to use $(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$ or $(1-\frac{1}{x^2})$

Comment: @JoshuaLochner: I didn't choose. It's clearly determined by the choice of rational approximation. $5 = (\frac{9}{4})^2 \times \boxed{?}$.

Comment: So is there a general way of saying it? $\sqrt x = $[rational approximation]$(1\pm\frac{1}{numerator Of Rational Approximation^2})^{0.5}$

Comment: @JoshuaLochner: Did you compute $\boxed{?}$ in my earlier comment? How about $5 = (\frac{18}{8})^2 \times \boxed{?}$? And how about $5 = (\frac{11}{5})^2 \times \boxed{?}$? It just so happens that for every continued fraction convergent $\frac{a}{b}$ for $\sqrt{5}$ we have $a^2-5b^2 \in \{1,-1\}$. This does not happen in general; try the convergents for $\sqrt{7}$ for example. However, it is easy to prove that consecutive convergents (for the standard continued fraction) always differ by a fraction with numerator $1$, but that's not what we want here.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, I did compute it... and I've spent a while trying to figure out something "General"... no success yet, but I have found some interesting things:

Comment: Paste this: http://pastebin.com/JP6cp1q5 into https://stackedit.io/editor to see what I have done so far

Comment: I have chosen specific rational approximations (Term 3 of the continued fraction usually), because it works with $ \frac{x}{y}(1\pm \frac{1}{x^2})$

Comment: @JoshuaLochner: Nice work. I suspect that for square-root of a positive integer there is always an infinite subsequence of convergents with the property that you want, but I'm not sure. Note that $\sqrt{19} = [4;2,1,3,1,2,8,...]$ requires using the 5th term to get what you want. In general I think stopping before the largest term will work, but I haven't tried proving it. Why don't you ask a new question about that? I would be interested to know too, so send me the link if you do!

Comment: @JoshuaLochner: Guess what? My hypothesis is correct, and follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions.

Comment: @user21820 Great! You really have helped me so much! Thanks! Is there a more efficient way I could possibly contact you? Or would you rather prefer to communicate over stackexchange?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43648/discussion-between-user21820-and-joshua-lochner).

Answer (score 2):

Your line of thinking is right:

In general, any convergent sequence can be converted into a series whose sum has the same limit: if $a_n$ is a sequence that converges to $a$ as $n$ tends to infinity, put $b_0 = a_0, b_1 = a_1 - a_0, \ldots, b_{i+1} = a_{i+1} - a_i, \ldots$; then $a_n  = \sum_{i=0}^n b_n$ and the $b_n$ comprise a convergent series whose sum is $a$.

So given a number $a$ that can be represented as a continued  fraction, if you take the $a_n$ to be the the partial convergents of the continued fraction, you can find a series whose sum is $a$. ("Partial convergent" is the jargon for truncating a continued fraction after a finite number of divisions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansions_of_.CF.80).

Comment: I checked that link out and it is very interesting! Especially the identity $\sqrt x = 1 + \frac{x-1}{1+\sqrt x}$ Which leads to the infinite series, by continually replacing $\sqrt x$ with  $1 + \frac{x-1}{1+\sqrt x}$ Now the question is, how do we change that continued fraction into an infinite sum?

Answer (score 2):

I wish to show you some of my favorite expansion of the golden ratio, and other things you can do with it.  It isn't necessarily a series, and the first is neither an algorithm or continued fraction.

We have

$$\phi=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}$$

You can see the truth in this simply because $\phi=\sqrt{1+\phi}$ is a true statement, both by the above form, and by calculating $\phi$ out, or any other ways.

In a similar manner, we have

$$\sqrt5=2\phi-1=-1+2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}$$

Albeit somewhat cheatery, but its a true statement.

We also have

$$\phi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(n)}{F(n-1)}$$

where $F(n)$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.  It converges rather quickly too.

With a modified Fibonacci sequence, we can get similar interesting things.

Allow $F_a(n)$ be the $n$th modified Fibonacci number, where

$$F_a(n)=F_a(n-1)+aF_a(n-2)$$

and $F_a(1)=F_a(2)=1$.

That small modification results in

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_a(n)}{F_a(n-1)}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{a}=-1/2+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{a-1/4}(n)}{F_{a-1/4}(n-1)}$$

(I'm pretty sure I calculated the limit correctly, but if someone could check my work, that'd be great)

Answer (score 1):

We might think and use one of the many approximation methods
to find the (real) root of a function.
For instance if we take $y = x^{\,2}  - p$ with $p$ any real number,
and adopt the simple *secant* method, starting with an over-estimate $x_q$ of 
of $\sqrt p$, we get
$$
\frac{{x_{n + 1}  - x_q }}
{{x_n  - x_q }} = \frac{{ - y_q }}
{{y_n  - y_q }} =  - \frac{{x_q ^{\,2}  - p}}
{{x_n ^{\,2}  - x_q ^{\,2} }}
$$
i.e.
$$
x_{n + 1}  = x_q  - \frac{{x_q ^{\,2}  - p}}
{{x_n  + x_q }}\quad \left| {\;x_0  = 0} \right.
$$
and for the delta
$$
x_{n + 1}  - x_n  = x_q  - x_n  - \frac{{x_q ^{\,2}  - p}}
{{x_n  + x_q }} =  - \frac{{x_n ^{\,2}  - p}}
{{x_n  + x_q }}
$$
Yet, unfortunately, this is not easily tranformable in a recurrence
that involves only the deltas and not their partial sums.